# How to validate unique pairs while being case insensitive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, unique, case-insensitive

I have a model for Guilds that have a "Name" and "Realm" attribute
I want to make it so that the "Name" and "Realm" pairings are unique regardless of case. Enforcing the case sensitivity is the only issue I have at them moment.

here's what I've got so far:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: :realm, case_sensitive: false
```

the [case_sensitive: false] part works but only for the first attribute(Name)

I'm currently using Rails 4.1.8, SQLite for developemnt and PG for Production
I really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's my understanding that this isn't supported. The `case_sensitive` option applies to the column being validated and the scope option applies only to columns in the same table.

You could try using PG's `lower` like so `scope: "lower(realm)"` but I suspect it'll fail when trying to access the column `table_name.lower(realm)`

What you need to do is replace that validator with a custom one.

```
class Model
  validate :your_validator

  private

  def your_validator
    if Model.
       where("LOWER(name) = ? AND LOWER(realm) = ?",
             name.downcase, realm.downcase).
       exists?
      # add errors here
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is probably the most straightforward way of doing it. I would just add that the author should re-evaluate if it is truly desired behavior to have `realm`s with different capitalizations be equal to each other instead of just conforming them before being saved (for example, making a before save action that downcases or upcases the realm value). In the latter case, your original code would work.

Comment: I thought of including that suggestion. But reading `Guilds` and `realm` made me think maybe this is a game-related project. And in games, users often use weird capitalizations that they would like to preserve.

Comment: Yes, in that case then I would definitely go with your method (I upvoted it).

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll definitley try this out